# A way to get discord bot to send a private message at a set time?

Tags: node.js, npm, discord, discord.js

This is my first discord bot I have created, and it is for an idea that is complicated but I find as fun. I was wanting to create a discord bot that can send private messages to random users at a certain time (in my case, once every 24 hours). Is there a way to code this? I am using Node.js/nodemon to run the code. I already have the bot running and online, I just need a way to do what I was hoping to accomplish! Thank you to anyone who could help me out with this!

Comment: The question is a bit broad so please try to include snippets of code that are causing you problem. Do take a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal-verifiable-complete-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I would also recommend that you take a look at [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) to achieve that you are trying to do. You could also potentially use [setTimeout()](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/) to achieve the same.

Answer (score -2):

I would do setTimeout of some sort if you have your bot hosted 24/7.... If not I would find some sort of npm package that shows the time and then do

```
if(npmpackagetime == 'Whatever time you want here') return user.send('Your message here')
```

And if you want to chose a random user, make an array of all the guild's users and then do `let newUser = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayName.length);` and then `newUser.send('Your message here');`

Comment: A` npmpackagetime` is not really something you should suggest. Either show a package or even better: CODE IT IN Node.js without any packages